# Separating sub-/superscripts out

Tags: macros, superscripts

I'm looking for a way of separating super-/subscripts (if they exist) from a LaTeX command argument. As an example, imagine you want to define a command that builds multisets from sets by placing an overline over the set name. A naive implementation of the command looks like this:

```
\newcommand{\mset}[1]{\overline{#1}}
```

This works well for sets that do not have sub-/superscripts; for example, for a set `R`, the multiset `\mset{R}` is equal to `\overline{R}`, as desired.

However, if the set has sub-/superscripts, then the typesetting looks really ugly as the overline stretches over the indexes as well. Thus, I would like a version of the `\mset` command that pushes sub-/superscripts outside `\overline`; for example, `\mset{R_1}` should expand to `\overline{R}_1`.

For this, it seems to me that I'd need a way to separate the sub-/superscripts out of the argument of \mset. Ideally, this would work regardless of whether the argument to \mset has no indexes, subscripts only, superscripts only, or both sub- and superscripts. Thus, `\mset{R}` would give `\overline{R}`, `\mset{R^1_2}` would give `\overline{R}^1_2`, and so on.

And just to immediately disqualify the obvious solution: I understand that I could pass sub-/superscripts to `\mset` as additional arguments. This, however, would be awkward as I want to nest the \mset command inside other commands so passing all the arguments separately would be quite clunky.

Comment: Simple solution for this: `\newcommand*\mset[1]{\overline#1}`. In any case, even simpler input would be `\mset R^1_2`, no need for braces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it, but I see no point: if the superscripts and subscripts should be outside the scope of the overline, place them outside the argument.

Note that the `k` feature of `xparse` I'm using is classified as experimental and may disappear in the future (not really likely).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\mset}[1]{\makemset#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\makemset}{mk_k^k_}{%
  \overline{#1}%
  \IfValueT{#2}{_{#2}}%
  \IfValueT{#3}{^{#3}}%
  \IfValueT{#4}{_{#4}}%
}

\begin{document}

$\mset{R}+\mset{R_1^2}+\mset{R^2_1}+\mset{R}_1^2$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank everyone for their answers -- they were all really helpful, but this one seems cleanest. Just a clarification as to the "why bother" question: I want to embed \mset into another command that accepts a set, converts it into a multiset, and does something with it. The set passed to this outer command can have sub-/superscripts, and it is more natural to pass it as, say, R_1^2, rather than requiring this outer command to accept several arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Even with your definition, you can use `\mset R_2^1` and it will work as you want. In any case, in case you definitely want `\mset{R_2^1}` you can use

```
\newcommand*\mset[1]{\overline#1}
```

Which will work as you want, and it will even work with the `\mset R_2^1` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It scans the input for instances of `\mset{...}` and rearranges the argument "on the fly", so that only leading single or multiple letters are part of the argument of `\mset`.  Whitespace before or after the left-hand curly brace is allowed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\mset}[1]{\overline{#1}}

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function mset_mod ( buff )
   return ( string.gsub ( buff, "\\mset[%s]-(%b{})",
              function ( x )
                 y = string.gsub ( x, "{[%s]-(%a+)(.*)}", "{%1}%2" )
                 return ("\\mset"..y )
              end ) )
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer", mset_mod, "mset_mod")
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}
$\mset{ R^{11}_{22}}$ $\mset {R_2^1}$ $\mset R$ $\mset{R}$

$\mset{  ABC }$ $\mset{ AB _1^{2}}$  
\end{document}
```